# Create Grid using javascript object model

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api

I got a requirement to create a GRID using JavaScript object model.
I have a list named SummaryResults with columns

- TaskID(Single line of text)
- Questions(Multi line of text)
- Response (drop-down with yes/no as options)
- Comments(Multi line of text)
- Status(drop-down with Saved/Submit as options)

For every TaskID there will be more than 30 questions and I want a grid to display list items for that particular TaskID(excluding Status column).
In the Grid, Response and Comments should be editable rest all columns should be in read-only mode.

There will me 3 buttons say Save, Submit and Cancel.

- Save - on click of Save, data should be saved to list with Status column to Saved
- Submit - on click of Submit, data should be saved to list with Status column to Submit
- Cancel - On click on Cancel, close the grid.

Please let me know how to go about it.

Comment: You could make a grid of inputs in side a table or div table which you then disable certain ones as per your requirements. Using SP's Rest API's you should be able to get, create and update items as required.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can make use jqgrid api.
Once you get the collection return from client side from shaepoint list then you can bind it to jqgrid
Here is the reference to [jqgrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)